# Congrats @sfdcfox on achieving 150k Reputation!

Tags: discussion

Many Congrats to [@sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox) achieving 150k.

You are an inspiration for many of us.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Thanks, Santanu, and everyone else in our community! It's been a lot of fun doing it, and I look forward to helping as many more people as I can in the future, too. I do hope that I inspire others to give back to the community as well. Salesforce isn't just about capturing leads or reporting on revenue, it's about the community of people that are all working together to make the world a better place, the Ohana that we are all a part of, and I'm grateful that I've found a place here.

Comment: Congrats.@sfdcfox

Comment: Congratulations @sfdcfox Keep up the good work.

Comment: Kudos @sfdcfox. You have been man at rescue for me many times.. Thank you so much for helping us out.. Please keep on the good work.

Comment: Congratulations @sfdcfox ! I am grateful for all the effort you have put into this community over the years.

Comment: @sfdcfox congratulations and 10q for helping us

Comment: @sfdcfox, Congrats. Hoping you will continue helping others a lot. Great work

Comment: Congratulations @sfdcfox

Answer (score 2):

Congrats @sfdcfox, You are an inspiration

Comment: How decrpt the MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 encrypted value in salesforce